# Do clients behind a router with both IPv4 and IPv6 use the same network?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, ipv6

My router has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Do the routers clients (that show public IP in either IPv4 or IPv6) share the same local area network? i.e. Can they ping each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

- You have two separate L3 networks: an IPv4 network and an IPv6 network. The two protocols share the same L2 domain (ethernet/wi-fi), but they do not interact with each other – a v4-only device cannot talk to an IPv6 address, and a v6-only device cannot reach an IPv4 address (except going through a special NAT64 translator).
- However, most new devices support both IPv4 *and* IPv6, i.e. are dual-stack and are connected to both networks simultaneously. (It's very unlikely that you have any IPv6-only devices.) So your v4-only devices *can* talk with dual-v4/v6 devices using their IPv4 address on both ends.